# How can I use JavaScript/jQuery to conditionally add a stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, conditional-comments

I've looked online for a suitable solution to the following issue and I can't seem to find a useful workaround;

We're using Umbraco CMS to display a client's website, this isn't allowing us to add in the usual conditional comments that one would do in the **< head >** of the HTML. Therefore I've been trying to find a way to get JavaScript or jQuery to *conditionally* display an IE9 specific stylesheet.

The options I've seen so far are as follows:

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 7) {
    $('head').append('<link>', {
        rel:  'stylesheet',
        type: 'text/css',
        href: 'css/ie9.css'
    });
}
```

And using **conditionizr** (which hasn't worked due to a console error on the ".add" function).

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing the tag name and its properties as two separate arguments to `append()`, you need to pass one fully constructed jQuery object (or HTML string).

```
$('head').append(
    $('<link>', {
        rel:  'stylesheet',
        type: 'text/css',
        href: 'css/ie9.css'
    })
);
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you! If you get time; i'd love to know why/how this worked - I know that .browser is deprecated/unused but the rest isn't clear

Comment: The problem wasn't with the condition at all.

Comment: The problem was that you were passing the tagname (`<link>`) and its properties object (`{rel: ...}`) as 2 separate arguments to `append()` - where as `append()` expects one fully constructed jQuery object or HTML string.

Comment: I've re-indented the code to make it clearer. Notice that you are passing just one jQuery object (which is a constructed, but not-in-DOM version of your link tag) to `append()`

Comment: Great, thanks very much! Lastly, is there a piece I need in order to get this to display conditionally? Currently the stylesheet is being brought across for all browsers and we only need it for IE9!